# Java debug help needed: display largest of 3 numbers

Tags: java, debugging, logic

This is a program that is supposed to prompt the user to enter three numbers and
then display the largest of these numbers. However, there are logic errors in it. I'm stuck on trying to figure out where this little bugger is. Please use your expertise to lend me a hand. I am a student, so please don't rage on me \:p

```
import java.util.*;
public class HA8LargestErr {
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int num3;

    public HA8LargestErr() {
        num1 = 0;
        num2 = 0;
        num3 = 0;
    }

    public void  getNumsFromUser() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter three numbers: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        num2 = input.nextInt();
        num3 = input.nextInt();
    }

    public int returnLargest() {
        if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3)
            return num1;
        if (num2 > num3 && num2 > num1)
            return num2;
        return num3;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HA8LargestErr data = new HA8LargestErr();

        data.getNumsFromUser();
        System.out.println ("The largest is : " + data.returnLargest());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give some indication of how your program fails? Like, what do you enter, and what does the program say?

Comment: It would help to know what type of input/output you get that seems wrong

Comment: are you allowed to use Math.max? If so in returnLargest you could do ... return Math.Max(num1,(Math.Max(num2,num3)));

Comment: It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, it works for me.

Comment: @flesk: Yeah, I just checked it out, too. I'm getting pretty curious to know why the OP thinks this has errors in it...

Comment: @samack: How does that suggestion in any way address the OP's question? Another, unrelated curiosity.

Comment: @Patrick Same here. I'm guessing it's a problem with the input he's trying to feed the program.

Comment: @Patrick87 I had not run the code and made an assumption :).

Comment: @samack: It's easy to see without running the code that his max function is correct though.

Comment: @flesk yes on further inspection it does look correct. The op said logic error since this is the only logic I asked if he knew about Math.Max...

Comment: I compiled and ran your code and was unable to find a case where it didn't return the correct result.

Comment: @GivenPie Please elaborate on "logical errors", what exactly are these errors and when do they occur?

Comment: Although you could (if you were so inclined) remove the `num2 > num1` check from your second if statement - it's unnecessary, since you already know it's either greater than or equal to as a result of not returning from the first check. :-)

Comment: Aha, if `num1 == num2 && num1 > num3` you get the wrong result I think. So, all `>`s should be replaced by `>=`.

Comment: Ben van Gompel makes a good point, what are you going to do if too numbers are the same?

Comment: @flesk: It's easy to see that not only novices makes silly mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your implementation of `returnLargest` with

```
public int returnLargest() {
    if (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3)
        return num1;
    if (num2 >= num3)
        return num2;
    return num3;
}
```

Or use `Math.max` as suggested above.

**Edit:**

You need to use `>=` instead of `>` because otherwise `num3` will be returned when `num1` and `num2` are equal and larger than `num3`.

Comment: +1 for finding the problem: needing to use >= instead of > (otherwise, num1=1, num2=1 and num3=0 returns 0). The other modifications - eliminating the second comparison in the second if and using Math.max instead of home-grown logic - are sort of off-topic if you ask me, but since you answer the question I guess this is OK. You could make this answer much more useful by making clear the reason why >= works and > fails.

Comment: THANK YOU. YOU SMART COOKIE!!! if(YOU > ME) { System.out.print("THANK YOU Ben van Gompel and KEvin"); }

Comment: @Patrcik87 Thanks. I've updated the answer to explain why this is needed. You are indeed correct about the `Math.max` being kinda off topic. The other change I think simplifies the implementation.